# magento API v2, extending sales/order class

Tags: api, magento, wsdl

I've been dealing with Magento API v2 for some days. I'm trying to extend the API to add a new method called "pago" (means payment) to the order/sales class.
By now I'm able to do it using the v1 WSDL, but when using v2 I get this error:

> Procedure 'salesOrderPago' not present in ...

My WSDL seems to be OK (http://www.hijole.com.py/ofertas/index.php/api/v2_soap/?wsdl)
I think my error is somewhere in **my api.xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <api>
        <resources>
            <sales_order translate="title" module="sales">
                <model>sales/order_api</model>
                <title>Order API</title>
                <acl>sales/order</acl>
                <methods>
                    <pago translate="title" module="sales">
                        <title>Acepta un pago</title>
                        <acl>sales/order/create</acl>
                    </pago>                 
                </methods>
            </sales_order>
         </resources>
     <resources_alias>
            <order>sales_order</order>
         </resources_alias>
        <v2>
            <resources_function_prefix>
                <order>salesOrder</order>
            </resources_function_prefix>
        </v2>
    </api>
</config>
```

This is my api/v2.php file

```
<?php
class Neurona_Pagoexpress_Model_Sales_Order_Api_V2 extends Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Api
{
    public function pago($ref, $medio, $moneda, $boleta)
    {
    try{
        //Crea invoice para la orden
        $invoice = Mage::getModel('sales/order_invoice_api');
        $invoice->create($ref, array(), 'PagoExpress - '.$boleta);

        $aut = "4894371870891274"; //Generar con algoritmo
        return array('00','Procedimiento correcto',$aut); // 00 = OK, Pago realizado
    }
    catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
        return array('99'); 
    }
}
}
```

This is my **conig.xml** file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <global>
        <models>
            <sales>
                <rewrite>
                    <order_api>Neurona_Pagoexpress_Model_Sales_Order_Api</order_api>
                    <order_api_v2>Neurona_Pagoexpress_Model_Sales_Order_Api_V2</order_api_v2>
                </rewrite>
            </sales>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

Here is my etc/wsdl.xml

```
    <definitions xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/">
        <message name="salesOrderPagoRequest">
            <part name="sessionId" type="xsd:string" />
            <part name="orderIncrementId" type="xsd:string" />
            <part name="orderMedio" type="xsd:string" />
            <part name="orderMoneda" type="xsd:string" />
            <part name="orderBoleta" type="xsd:string" />
        </message>
        <message name="salesOrderPagoResponse">
            <part name="result" type="typens:ArrayOfString" />
        </message>

        <portType>
            <operation name="salesOrderPago">
                <documentation>Implementa el pago de una factura</documentation>
                <input message="typens:salesOrderPagoRequest" />
                <output message="typens:salesOrderPagoResponse" />
            </operation>
         </portType>

        <binding>
            <operation name="salesOrderPago">
                <soap:operation soapAction="urn:{{var wsdl.handler}}Action" />
                <input>
                    <soap:body namespace="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}" use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
                </input>
                <output>
                    <soap:body namespace="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}" use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
                </output>
            </operation>
        </binding>
    </definitions>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes. The idea is to extend native Magento API.

Comment: I don't know whether this is correct <acl>sales/order/create</acl>

Comment: Jevgeni, thanks for your interest. But I found the module is working today after I requested a support to my Hosting company. It seems it was a cache issue. THANKS AGAIN

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution later: Just restart Apache. It seems to be a wsdl cache issue.