# Magento. How to export own custom API extension so other can also use?

Tags: php, magento

I created my custom SOAP additional method in the Magento API V2 according to some tutorials on the web (e.g. [magento API v2, extending sales/order class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9201036/magento-api-v2-extending-sales-order-class)).

Now my structure looks like this:

```
app/etc/modules/
-Company_namespace.xml
app/code/local/Company/namespace/
-etc/
--wsdl.xml
--api.xml
--config.xml
-Model/Customer/Customer/Api/
--V2.php
```

I would like to expose my extension to other Magento instance. How I can do that? I don't want people to copy&paste my structure to their installations. I would prefer pack it into archive and somehow install it in another installation. How is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specifics are a little long for a Stack Overflow answer, but you have a few options.

The official thing you want to do is create a [Magento Connect](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/7_-_magento_connect/creating_magento_connect_extension_package) extension package.  Connect is Magento's built in package manager, and the format used by the Magento Connect website.  There [are scripts](http://alanstorm.com/magento_connect_from_tar) (self-link) out there that can convert a tar archive into a Magento Connect package.

There's been some [unofficial movement](http://alanstorm.com/php_composer_magento_tutorial) by the independent community of Magento developers to provide PHP Composer support for Magento as well.  If you're into modern PHP you may want to continue your investigations along those lines.